# How to get custom table from data fetch by form id in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, model

How to get custom table form table by form_id for custom table in magento 2.3.1?

try this but it's not working

custom table screen short:

[image]

> Vendor\Module\Block\Form.php

```
 <?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   protected $collectionFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ContactForms\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

 public function getLoadForm($form_id)
  {
    return $this->collectionFactory->create()->load($form_id);
  }
}
```

> customTemplate.phtml

```
<?php
   $formsCollection = $block->getLoadForm(form_id);

   echo $formsCollection->getTitle();
?>
```

Comment: You didn't pass form id in your phtml file.

Comment: @RohanHapani i passed form id but it's Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: form_id issue face

Comment: It should be variable or direct int value.

Comment: @RohanHapani How to fetch form data in phtml file please advance thank for help.

Comment: Just try this : $form_id = 1; $formsCollection = $block->getLoadForm($form_id); in phtml file.

Comment: @RohanHapani this is working but one question how to dynamically use form_id in phtml file currently padd form_id = 3 show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117248/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-ravindrasinh-zala).

Comment: @RohanHapani <?php
$form_id = 3;
$formsCollection = $block->getLoadForm($form_id);
foreach ($formsCollection as $form) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($form->getData());
}
?>

Comment: @RohanHapani Now I have particular record fetch data like form_id = 3 but currently show all table records